# Is there a specific REST API for getting user roles for a specific user under a service account to check if the user can access resources?

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-platform

I am a total newbie to GCP so bear with me. I have a task to list all the roles of a specific user under a projects and I tried different APIs but was not getting anywhere. So any help is appreciated.

`POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/{resource=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*}:getIamPolicy`
For this above API I got roles and the list of user who has those roles. But I wanted for a specific user.

I have checked most of the APIs form this link: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: Are you trying to get the IAM members assigned permissions "on" a service account or IAM members that have permissions to a project. You might be misunderstanding how permissions work in Google Cloud.

Comment: To get a list of permissions assigned to IAM members for a project use this API: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy

Comment: To get a list of permissions assigned to IAM members for a service account use this API: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/getIamPolicy

Answer (score 0):

The getIamPolicy method you've referred to is the most suitable API method you're going to get for this task. There's no API that will allow you to get all roles for a specific user.

IAM policies are organised under the [hierarchy of resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#how_cloud_iam_works). The user is bound to a given role at a given level of the hierarchy. The REST API will only allow you to query the policies at resource level.

The only way to review all of a user's bindings at project-level would be via the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).